# Is there a way to tell Vowpal Wabbit to ignore variables for training?

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I've created a test and train set in the vowpal wabbit format (.vw).  I'd like to explore the effect of dropping various variables, however I don't want to regenerate my train set from scratch each time.  Is there a way to tell VW to only attend to specific inputs or to ignore specific inputs?

I'm aware that I can use namespaces with --ignore, but it would appear to do what I want I would have to create a separate namespace for each variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you noted, you can currently apply `--ignore` only to name-spaces.  Improvements to the code are always welcome.  If you're on Unix, you should be able to remove features easily with something like `perl -pe 's/ variable_name(?::[0-9.]+)?//'`